# Suggestion for improving cli wrapper over Apache Commons CLI

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have following cli wrapper:

```java
public class CLIUtil
{
    // some private variable and other methods     

    public CLIUtil(final String[] args, final Options commandLineOptions) throws ParseException
    {
        Validate.notEmpty(args);
        Validate.notNull(commandLineOptions);
        this.commandLineOptions = commandLineOptions;
        this.command = this.parser.parse(this.commandLineOptions, args);
    }

    public void printHelp(final String executableName)
    {
        Validate.notEmpty(executableName);
        final HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        formatter.printHelp(executableName, this.commandLineOptions);
    }
}
```

Which have following problems:
As we are throwing exception in constructor:

1. if args as null. There is no way to printHelp.
2. if args are invalid. There is no way to printHelp.

I am thinking of following solution:

Solution 1:

```java
public CLIUtil(final String executableName, final Options commandLineOptions) throws ParseException
{
    Validate.notNull(commandLineOptions);
    this.commandLineOptions = commandLineOptions;
    this.executableName = executableName;
}

public void parseArgs(final String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    Validate.notEmpty(args);
    this.command = this.parser.parse(this.commandLineOptions, args);
}
```

Problem with this solution is:

1. User need to call set after constructor. so we are letting client to control the flow.

Solution 2:

```java
public CLIUtil(final String executableName, String[] args, final Options commandLineOptions) throws ParseException
{
    if (null == args) {
        // show help and throw illegal arg
    }

    Validate.notNull(commandLineOptions);
    this.commandLineOptions = commandLineOptions;
    this.executableName = executableName;

    try {
        this.command = this.parser.parse(this.commandLineOptions, args);
    } catch (Parse...) {
        // catch exception and show error and printhelp followed by
        // throw same exception 
    }
}
```

Problem with this solution is:
1) Random placement of validation rule.

Do you have a suggestion which solution is better or suggested improvement?

Comment: why invent the wheel? there is [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Comment: @sharonbn I am using Apache common only. It is wrapper over that.

Comment: oh ok, why not say so explicitly?